# How to keep asking for a new ID until it is no longer already taken

Tags: c#, loops, file-handling

There is an issue with my current code, not sure how I can keep looping through my code while the ID length != 8 and the ID number is already taken. This may be as simple as adding in a new procedure but I am unsure.

```
static void GetIDInput(ref int ID)
{

    int tempID = 0;

    while (tempID.ToString().Length != 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired ID number");
        tempID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    ID = tempID;
}

static void AddStock()
{

    int stockQuantity = 0;
    double stockPrice = 0.00;
    string stockName = "";
    string s = ""; // Being Lazy here, to convert to when needed.
    int tempID = 0;
    int IDNumber = 0;
    string lineValues;
    bool taken = false;

    GetIDInput(ref tempID);

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
    {
        while (sr.EndOfStream == false && taken != true)
        {
            lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

            if (lineValues.Contains(tempID.ToString()))
            {
                taken = true;
            }
            else
            {
                taken = false;
            }
        }

        if (taken == false)
        {
            IDNumber = tempID;
        }
        else if (taken == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry this ID is already taken, try again");
            // Want to re-loop  here but not sure how...
        }
    }


    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Stockfile.txt", true))
    {
        s = IDNumber.ToString();
        sw.Write(s + "\t"); // Will only accept an 8 figure digit so is safe to have a single value here.

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Stockfile.txt", true))
        {
            s = IDNumber.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t"); // Will only accept an 8 figure digit so is safe to have a single value here.

            while (stockName.Length <= 2) // No fancy brands here......
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the name of the stock: ");
                stockName = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            s = stockName;
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            while (stockQuantity < 1) // Running a small shop here...
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the quanity of stock: ");
                stockQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            s = stockQuantity.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            while (stockPrice < 0.01) // Running a very small shop....
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the price of the stock: ");
                stockPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            s = stockPrice.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            sw.WriteLine(); // TO create the new line.....

        }
```

Purpose of this is to check that in the file the ID number hasn't already been taken as that would be an error for when a user looks up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about the words you said yourself

> Keep looping through my code while the ID length != 8 and the number
>   is taken

And shuffle exactly what you have around to do that.

I took the liberty to ditch the ref param as well, feel free to put it back

```
static int GetIDInput()
{

    int tempID = 0;
    bool taken = true;
    bool isInputValid = false;

    while (taken == true && isInputValid == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired ID number");
        tempID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (tempID.ToString().Length != 8)
        {
            isInputValid = false;
            Console.WriteLine("ID number must be 8 digits long.")
        }
        else
        {
            isInputValid = true;
        }

        if (isInputValid) // this wont run if the input wasnt 8 characters, so the loop will restart
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
            {
                while (sr.EndOfStream == false && taken != true)
                {
                    lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (lineValues.Contains(tempID.ToString()))
                    {
                        taken = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        taken = false;
                    }
                }

                if (taken == false)
                {
                    ID = tempID;
                }
                else if (taken == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry this ID is already taken, try again");
                    // statements will lead us back to the while loop and taken == true so it will run again
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tempID;
}



static void AddStock()
{
    int stockQuantity = 0;
    double stockPrice = 0.00;
    string stockName = "";
    string s = ""; // Being Lazy here, to convert to when needed.
    int IDNumber = 0;
    string lineValues;

    IDNumber = GetIDInput();

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Stockfile.txt", true))
    {
        s = IDNumber.ToString();
        sw.Write(s + "\t"); // Will only accept an 8 figure digit so is safe to have a single value here.

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Stockfile.txt", true))
        {
            s = IDNumber.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t"); // Will only accept an 8 figure digit so is safe to have a single value here.

            while (stockName.Length <= 2) // No fancy brands here......
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the name of the stock: ");
                stockName = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            s = stockName;
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            while (stockQuantity < 1) // Running a small shop here...
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the quanity of stock: ");
                stockQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            s = stockQuantity.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            while (stockPrice < 0.01) // Running a very small shop....
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the price of the stock: ");
                stockPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            s = stockPrice.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            sw.WriteLine(); // TO create the new line.....

        }
```

I didn't actually run this so you may need to error check.

Comment: Lookss good but even if there is already an entry it seems to skip over and go straight into the name of stock, this may just be me error not sue though

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. It will keep asking for an ID until the user inputs one that is not already used:

```
//Get the input
static int GetIDInput()
{
    int id;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired ID number");
        id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    while (isIDAlreadyUsed(id));
    return id;
}

// Check if ID is already used
public static bool isIDAlreadyUsed(int IDToCheck)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string lineValues = sr.ReadLine();
            if(lineValues.Contains(IDToCheck.ToString())
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static void AddStock()
{
    // Your init
    // ...
    int id = GetIDInput(); // Get the ID

    //... Your logic to apply
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay for those interested,@plast1k had the original code, just edited for my needs.

```
static int GetIDInput()
    {

        int tempID = 0;
        bool taken = false;
        bool isInputValid = false;
        string lineValues;

        while (isInputValid == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired ID number");
            tempID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (tempID.ToString().Length != 8)
            {
                isInputValid = false;
                Console.WriteLine("ID number must be 8 digits long.");
            }
            else if (tempID.ToString().Length == 8)
            {
                isInputValid = true;
            }

            if (isInputValid) // this wont run if the input wasnt 8 characters, so the loop will restart
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
                {
                    while (sr.EndOfStream == false && taken != true)
                    {
                        lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

                        if (lineValues.Contains(tempID.ToString()))
                        {
                            taken = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            taken = false;
                        }


                        if (taken == false)
                        {

                        }
                        else if (taken == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sorry this ID is already taken, try again");

                            isInputValid = false;
                            // statements will lead us back to the while loop and taken == true so it will run again
                        }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        return tempID;
    }
```